# What is CI/CD Pipeline in DevOps?

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud

I just graduated with a non-tech background. As a person from a non-IT Background is DevOps a good career choice? Is it a good time to enroll in **[devops training](https://youtu.be/YzwD02ImKY4)**?

Answer (score 1):

CI = Continous Integration, CD = Continous Delivery.

**What is CI/CD**:
Continuous Integration (**CI**) means automatically testing each change made to your codebase as soon as possible. Continuous delivery (**CD**) follows this testing and pushes changes to a staging or production system.

**Further information:**
Data pipelines, web services, apps etc. all of this is just code that needs to run on some computer that executes and runs the code. Normally one separates the dev (development) from the prod (production) environment. Code will change over time, new features, new requirements, bug fixes etc. will result in more and more code over time and will create new versions and releases of your software. DevOps and CI/CD is an essential part of successful software development. And this will remain like this as long as there will be software devlopment.

**To answer your question: Is DevOps a good career choice?**
Whoever is serious with IT and software development, needs to know about DevOps. It's definitely a domain where you can learn a lot. If you plan to stay in some IT related career path, I think knowledge about DevOps will always remain helpful for you. My advice is: try to find out what is it you like to do and investigate your time in learning and improving your knowledge on this. It doesn't matter if your background is IT or not. If you are willing to put in the effort and learn, you will  find your way.